# Letter combination 'fi' won't display using mathgifg.sty

Tags: fonts

The title says it all. I am using the erdc package and the first challenge was to get all the fonts installed properly. Figured that out and can get pdf output, but any word that has an 'fi' combination has an open square where 'fi' should be.

I think the culprit is in the mathgifg.sty file used by the erdc package:

```
%mathgifg.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{mathgifg}
    [2009/07/08 v0.4 Using Georgia and Franklin Gothic in LaTeX]
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{textcomp}
    \RequirePackage{keyval}
    \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{xifg}
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{xjgi}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{zjgi}{m}{n}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{zjgi}{m}{it}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{zjgi}{m}{n}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{zjgi}{m}{n}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{sfletters}{OML}{zifg}{k}{n}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{bfletters}{OML}{zifg}{d}{n}
    \SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{zifg}{d}{n}
    \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{sfletters}
    \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{bfletters}
    \DeclareRobustCommand\hbar{{%
     \dimen@.03em%
     \dimen@ii0.001em%
     \def\@tempa##1##2{{%
       \lower##1\dimen@\rlap{\kern##1\dimen@ii\the##2 0\char22}}}%
     \mathchoice\@tempa\@ne\textfont
                \@tempa\@ne\textfont
                \@tempa\defaultscriptratio\scriptfont
                \@tempa\defaultscriptscriptratio\scriptscriptfont
      h}}
    \let\s@vedhbar\hbar
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \@ifpackageloaded{amsfonts}{\let\hbar\s@vedhbar}{}}
    \endinput
```

And a minimal code example:

```
\documentclass{erdc}

\begin{document}
find official
\end{document}
```

Can anyone suggest what I might do to fix this problem?

UPDATE: One way to fix this is to wrap the 'i' in brackets so the following minimal example produces proper output:

```
\documentclass{erdc}

\begin{document}
f{i}nd off{i}cial
\end{document}
```

This a suboptimal fix as I would hate to have to edit for every occurence of 'fi' in a document. So I am still interested in alternatives.

Comment: They are part of the Windows distribution and are included as *.ttf in c:\windows\fonts. All that is required is that you move a copy of them into your local installation directory after converting them to *.pfb files.

Comment: The package installed when I ran TeX Live 2018 from the ctan site. I just had a huge font issue because, as you said, the fonts aren't free and cannot be distributed open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the package from CTAN and looked at the file `t1xjgi.fd`, which contains

```latex
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{xjgi}{m}{n}{
   <-> xjgim8t
}{}
```

OK, let's look at `xjgim8t.vf` the virtual font corresponding to the desired font with `vftovp`. After a long series of warnings (not so important), we find the ligature table

```
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL O 25)
   (LIG O 55 O 26)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 33)
   (LIG C i O 36)
   (LIG C l O 37)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 41)
   (LIG O 140 O 275)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 47)
   (LIG O 47 O 21)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 54)
   (LIG O 54 O 22)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 55)
   (LIG O 55 O 25)
   (LIG O 177 O 177)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 74)
   (LIG O 74 O 23)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 76)
   (LIG O 76 O 24)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 77)
   (LIG O 140 O 276)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 140)
   (LIG O 140 O 20)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 34)
   (LIG C f O 33)
   (LIG C l O 35)
   (STOP)
   )
```

Well this says that when TeX finds an `f` followed by another `f`, the character in slot octal 33 should be used; this too has an entry in the ligature table: if it is followed by `i`, the character in slot octal 36 should be used in place of the combination `ffi`. Now look at what we find for the description of the character:

```
(CHARACTER O 36
   (CHARWD R 0.908)
   (CHARHT R 0.7515)
   (MAP
      )
   )
```

which means that nothing apart from a white space will be printed.

That's all: the font metrics and maps are badly written. You're out of luck unless you rework the maps yourself.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this for me. I have no idea how to rework the maps at this point and don't feel like exploring it further now. I guess my sub-optimal solution from my original post has just become the optimal solution. Lol!

Comment: @LaarsHelenius One could think to remove the `ffl` and `ffi` ligatures from the .vf files. It's not so big a work, although not so easy either.